# VBA to Vlookup values across multiple rows and columns Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a worksheet like such:

```
Name   Num1 Num2 Num3 Num4
test1   
test2   
test3   


test3   7%   6%   6%   6%
test1   4%   5%   4%   5%
test2   6%   6%   5%   4%
```

I am trying to create a macro button that copies the values from the below part of the worksheet to the above empty part based on the name column value.

I was thinking it could be using a `vlookup`.

The values in the below part are in formula form so they would need to be pasted special as values with number formatting.

The result is as follows:

---

```
Name   Num1 Num2 Num3 Num4
test1   4%   5%   4%   5%
test2   6%   6%   5%   4%
test3   7%   6%   6%   6%


test3   7%   6%   6%   6%
test1   4%   5%   4%   5%
test2   6%   6%   5%   4%
```

---

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Sub COPY()

  With Range("B2:B4")
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$8:$M$10,2,0)"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
End Sub
```

---

The above code works for one column, but I can't figure out how to loop and do it over column 3, 4, 5 etc..

Result from above code:

```
Name   Num1 Num2 Num3 Num4
test1   4%   
test2   6%   
test3   7%   


test3   7%   6%   6%   6%
test1   4%   5%   4%   5%
test2   6%   6%   5%   4%
```

---

Thanks for the help. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Maybe `=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$8:$M$10,column(),0)` to make it dynamic?

Comment: Thanks. But would the range not need to change too?

Comment: Which range is that?

Comment: `With Range("B2:B4")`

Comment: Sorry, don't follow. But why are you using VBA for this at all?

Comment: `.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,R8C1:R10C13,COLUMN(),0)"`

Comment: @user3819867 That returns #N/A in cell B2

Comment: @user3819867's formula looks to me, you might have to adjust ranges for your layout.

Comment: @user3819867 Can you explain how your formula works please?

Comment: It uses relative distances instead of range addresses. For cell `B2` it translates to `=VLOOKUP($A2;$A$8:$M$10;COLUMN();0)`, for cell `E4` it translates to `=VLOOKUP($A4;$A$8:$M$10;COLUMN();0)`. You can read about R1C1 references [here](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008803_Understanding_R1C1_References.html).

Comment: @user3819867 Should the final formula look like this?`Sub COPY()

  With Range("B2:B4")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,R8C1:R10C13,COLUMN(),0)"
    .Value = .Value
  End With
End Sub`

Comment: `Range("B2:E4")`

Comment: @user3819867 Thanks! It works for first column, but #N/A for others

Comment: @SeanG123 make sure you use `C1` where I did, which roughly translates to `$A` instead of `A`.

Comment: @user3819867 Thanks for the help!! I don't really understand where the numbers in RC are coming from. VLOOKUP(RC1,R8C1:R10C13

Comment: Actually I got it! What if the values are percentages, how do I get them to not copy as 0%?

Comment: @user3819867 - if you want to post as an answer I'll give you a vote.

Answer (score 0):

for source range A6:E9 (with col headings) and target range A1:E4 (with col headings). You can adjust col.column in the formula to match the desired col number in the source range

```
Sub vlkup()

Dim col As Range

For Each col In Range("B2:E4").Columns

With col
.Formula = "=VLOOKUP($A2,$A$6:$E$9," & col.Column & ",False)"
.Value = .Value ' to convert formula to values
End With

Next

End Sub
```